# Firebase database query with vue js

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Realtime Database.
Below I enclose my firebase structure:

[image: Firebase structure]

I am trying to recive all IDs where `tags` are equal to my `payload`(e.g. Phones)

I tried following query

```
firebase.database().ref('Questionnaires').orderByChild('tags').equalTo(payload).once("value")
        .then((data) => {
          commit('setLoading', false)
          console.log("Result", data.val())
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          commit('setLoading', false)
          console.log(error)
        })
```

But in effect I am reciving `data.val() = null`

I tried various approaches but still got `null`

Is it possible to construct that query with that data structure ? If yes please teach me. I am out of ideas.

Comment: Tour `tags` node doesn't have a child key matching your `payload`, so this query won't work. Your current data structure makes it easy to look up the tags for a questionnaire, but it does not make it easy to look up the questionnaires for a tag. To allow the latter, you'll want to add a secondary data structure `tags` and store the tag name and all questionnaire IDs under that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Comment: Thank You Frank, your link and answer has opened my eyes.

Answer (score -1):

I've heard relationships is a nightmare to maintain in firebase, my guess is that tags is another firebase collection? If so, switch over to another dbsm  before it is too late.